# Rails - creating a notification system similar to that of Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie trying to make his very first web application. What I have in mind right now is a notification system similar to that of Facebook. I did a quick search to see what other people have talked about the subject, and saw many different opinions on how to approach the problem: some people recommend doing the process in the background using Resque/Delayed Job/Beanstalkd while others point to gems like Mailboxer.

Why is there a need to process the job in the background? Is it only for incoming messages? Also, would Delayed Job suffice for a simple notification system? I've heard beanstalkd is the fastest but has no support for Windows.

Any help/advice/answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi! when you say notification system, are you referring to the real time notification system (like the popup) or just the one at the top (like an inbox of sorts?)

Comment: Just the one at the top :)

Comment: in that case, you only need to add a separate model that creates the notifications.  Other suggest a background job because you may be creating more than 1 notification record for a single activity which may be time consuming.  This is just a simple app so you should be able to start working on it if you've any tutorials.  When you get stuck, just post a different question and we'll see what we can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run a rake task or a delayed job.

On a web application, you have to send the answer to the user right away, you don't want to make him waiting until you do all the processing of broadcasting, so you just save the publication and show him the success message.

Then, you process the notification, and you broadcast this notification to all the subscriber, this process may take a bit (imagine someone with 2,000 friends).

Finally, if you want a notification system to show the realtime notifications, the background process could broadcast the message though javascript and websockets, have a look at [Best Ruby on Rails WebSocket tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767268/best-ruby-on-rails-websocket-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this excellent video and text tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity it may point you to the right direction

Also on the same website you will find a lot of useful informations